# Repeat a function 3 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm programming the "Rock, paper, scissors". I want now to run the function I added below 3 times. I tried using a `for _ in range(s)` but printed the same result 3 times.

```
import random

OPTIONS = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

def get_user_input():
    user_choice = input("Select your play (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
    return user_choice

def random_choice():
    computer_choice = random.choice(OPTIONS)
    return computer_choice

def game(user_choice, computer_choice):
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nDraw.")
    else:
        if computer_choice == "Rock" and user_choice == "Paper":
            print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nYou won!")
        if computer_choice == "Rock" and user_choice == "Scissors":
            print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nYou lost...")
        if computer_choice == "Paper" and user_choice == "Scissors":
            print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nYou won!")
        if computer_choice == "Paper" and user_choice == "Rock":
            print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nYou lost...")
        if computer_choice == "Scissors" and user_choice == "Rock":
            print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nYou won!")
        if computer_choice == "Scissors" and user_choice == "Paper":
            print(f"You selected: {user_choice}.\nComputer selected: {computer_choice}.\nYou lost...")

def main():
    user_choice = get_user_input()
    computer_choice = random_choice()
    for _ in range(3):
        if game(user_choice, computer_choice):
            break
        else:
            print("Game has ended!")

main()
```

Any tips on how to implement three rounds?

Comment: You have assigned the result of the `random_choice` and the user input and now this values are fixed. So you just use the same values three times. Try `game(get_user_input(), random_choice()):`

Comment: Also, you might want to think of [`elif`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Comment: @Cpt.Hook We're should I type get_user_input() and random_choice() to? I tried inside main function but did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to rework your code in main()

```
def main():

    for _ in range(3):
        user_choice = get_user_input()
        computer_choice = random_choice()
        game(user_choice, computer_choice)

    print("Game has ended!")
```

Try something like this

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Morgan

Answer (score 1):

Your program works great! just one small placement error, the random_choice needs to change with every iteration of the loop so I moved the random_choice assignment variable in and that solved the problem. This is also if you want the player to only be able to make one choice.

```
def main():
    user_choice = get_user_input()
    for _ in range(3):
        computer_choice = random_choice()
        game('Rock', computer_choice)
    print("Game has ended!")

main()
```

if you want the player to pick every round then it would look like this;

```
def main():
    for _ in range(3):
        user_choice = get_user_input()
        computer_choice = random_choice()
        game('Rock', computer_choice)
    print("Game has ended!")
            

main()
```

Comment: Thank you kidcoolness!! Morgan and you posted the same solution. Thank you to you both!